# Отношения между таблицами SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Имеются 4 таблицы:
Магазины, Учебники, Поставки, Школы.

Какие отношения между ними?

```
Магазины - Учебники - М : М
Магазины - Поставки - 1 : М
Школы - Поставки    - М : 1
```

Так или я ошибся?

Уточнение: Поставки - это таблица в которой фиксируется дата и количество поставок.

Comment: А что такое Поставки?

Comment: Таблица в которой фиксируется дата и количество поставок

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, как не соответствующего теме, потому что вопрос о предметной области, а не о программировании.